# Initializing base part of the derived struct / Unexpected packing derived struct fields to alignment gap of the base struct

Tags: c++, inheritance, alignment, language-lawyer

It was unexpectedly discovered, that clang++7 allows itself to tightly pack fields of the derived struct (struct "B" with field "B::u16_gap" in the example below) to the alignment gap of the base struct (struct "A"). But function "zero_init" in the example expects it's input to be the "A"-object with non-used alignment gap, so it can be overwritten by "memcpy". This function "zero_init", of course, overwrites any value of the "B::u16_gap"-field, when applied to "B"-object.

```
// compilation: clang++-7 -std=c++17 test.cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    std::uint32_t u32 = 0;
    std::uint16_t u16 = 0;
};

void zero_init(A& a) {
    static constexpr A zero = {};
    std::memcpy(&a, &zero, sizeof(A));
};

struct B: public A {
    std::uint16_t u16_gap = 0;
};

static_assert(sizeof(A) == 8);
static_assert(sizeof(B) == 8); // clang++-7 packs additional field "B::u16_gap" to the alignment gap of the A (for g++-7 it is not true)

int main() {
    B b;
    A& a = b;
    b.u16_gap = 123;
    zero_init(a);
    std::cout << b.u16_gap << std::endl; // writes "0" instead of expected "123"
}
```

Where is the ill-formed part (deviation from "well behavior" rules of the C++17 standard) in this code?

Comment: Why do you expect 123? You zero it after that.

Comment: Because "zero_init" is supposed to touch only "A"-part of the "B"-object. It legally (at the first glance) writes only to the "A"-base struct area.

Comment: Suggest you add the [language-lawyer] tag, as this looks decidedly odd.  Your testing would suggest that the `A` and `B` parts of the structure would have the same address which I think is incorrect re the standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like your static assert shows, the size of an A is 8 bytes.
This means your static "zero" A-Object consists of 8 bytes of zeros.
`memcpy` doesn't know about types, so you copy the plain 8 bytes to the address of `a` and thus overwrite the `u16_gap` field, which is stored in those 8 bytes, like your second assert shows.

If you want to change this, you can just copy 6 bytes and it should work.

Comment: But how functions like "zero_init" will know, that it is forbidden to write to the alignment gaps? As far as I know, alignment gaps can be written by any value.

Comment: It doesn't know that this is forbidden, it is your function. It just copies 8 bytes since this is the size of A (with the alignment).

Comment: For now, my best guess is:
since struct "A" and "B" are not POD (_is it true?_), all operations (construction, assignment, etc) can be performed only by very accurate functions, non-touching alignment gaps.

Comment: They are not PODs, but I would suggest using like a constructor or something like that and not manually memory handling, since this is unsafe in this case

Comment: Thank you. There can be conclusion: memcpy-like treatment is only for PODs, where "modern" non-PODs can be treated only by their legal constructors and assignment operators. Even if they looks like PODs.

Comment: Always have in mind that memory layout may be implementation-defined. The order is always the same but the compiler can pad after every element he wants and noone guarantees you if he does etc.